# Python, webscraping in website with embedded java script

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping a website.

After these lines of code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

parse_soup = soup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

I get some html and in the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            
            window.ContextPath = "/BOBIBOBI/Public/";
            
        window.ControllerName = "Pubblicazioni";
        window.ActionName = "Index";
        window.LoginUrl = "/BOBIBOBI/Account/Login";
        window.Locale = "it";
    </script>
<script src="/BOBIBOBI/Bundles/all?v=x1x2x3x4x5x6x"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#table").DataTable({
            order: [],
            dom: "<'row actions'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'<'pull-right input-group input-group-sm'f<'input-group-btn insert'>>>><'row'<'col-sm-12 table-wrapper'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4 text-center'><'col-sm-4'p>>",
            drawCallback: function (settings) {
                var csrf = $("form.filter [name='__RequestVerificationToken']");
                $(".postlink-download").each(function () {
                    var params = $(this).data("params");
                    if (params) {
                        params[csrf.attr("name")] = csrf.val();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).on("beforeDetailInline", function (e, tr, data) {
            $("#filter_Titolo_").val($(data[0]).data("value"));
            $("#filter_Id_").val($(data[3]).data("value"));
            $("#filter_ExtKey_").val($(data[4]).data("value"));
            $("#filter_TipoPubblicazione_").val($(data[5]).data("value"));
            $("#filter_SheetName_").val($(data[8]).data("value"));
            $("#modalTitleDetails").text("BOBIBOBI " + data[7]);
            $("#detail-date").text(tr.find("td:eq(1)").text());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("form.filter").serialize(),
                url: "/BOBIBOBI/Public/Pubblicazioni/Detail",
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    $("#divDetails").html(data);
                    $("#tableDetails").DataTable({
                        order: [],
                        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 table-wrapper'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'p>>"
                    });
                    $("#modalDetails").modal("show");
                }
            });
        }).on("beforeCreateActionUrl", function (e, tr, data, className) {
            if (className === "detail-download") {
                return "/BOBIBOBI/Public/Pubblicazioni/ExportDetails";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to scrape out the tables contained in the website, authentication worked fine. I am not used to java with python.

I want to get some data from a request like this:

```
r = requests.post(SOURCE_URL, data=WHATDATA,  headers=HEADERS, verify=False)
```

I know source_url and headers.
I know tables names and their publication dates.
My question is: what shall I put as in WHATDATA so that I can write:

```
data_parsed = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

and get data_parsed with my tables in. Hope this is clear, otherwise I can clarify more.

Thank you

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: @Koenigsberg
javascript-related. Anyway hope the core is clear

Comment: Okay. I am fixing your tag.

Comment: @Koenigsberg
totally approved. Thanks

Comment: If the site you're trying to scrape, requires authentication, then data you send, is your credentials, usually your username and password!!! But remember for some websites it's more than your username and password. If there is a form to submit for authentication, pay attention if there is a hidden field to submit along with your username and password. Also look for your credentials and see if they're sent as "plain text" or as "hashed values". Also look for "csrf tokens", some website use those. So all of these, if exist, would be sent to the server in a data dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, I think I am working on the same website... this solution worked for me, you have to create JSON with parameters from the row and add it as an attribute:

```
var data = $('#table').DataTable().rows().data().toArray()[0];
var titolo = $(data[0]).data("value");
var id = $(data[3]).data("value");
var extkey = $(data[4]).data("value");
var tipopubb = $(data[5]).data("value");
var sheet = $(data[8]).data("value");
var idsezione = $(data[9]).data("value");
var idparent =  $(data[2]).data("pk");
var token = $("form.filter [name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

var params = {
    details: {
        Titolo: titolo,
        Id: id,
        ExtKey: extkey,
        TipoPubblicazione: tipopubb,
        SheetName: sheet,
        IdSezione: idsezione,
        ParentId: idparent
    },
    __RequestVerificationToken: token
};

var e = new Event('click');
var link = $('<a class="detail-download">').attr("href", "/sunset/Public/Pubblicazioni/ExportDetails").data("params", params).get(0);

submitAjax(e, link);
```